# ViewController rightSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14a508110'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-m1

I am learning an IOS tutorial from the scratch.
When I was learning the function for switching the state between two UISwitches, I got an error as below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[controlFun.ViewController rightSwitch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14a508110'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 802.6 - Device: iPhone 13 mini (D69A2208-197A-44A5-8CEF-BD9CBDA18565) - Runtime: iOS 15.4 (19E240) - DeviceType: iPhone 13 mini
```

My Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var doSomethingButton: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var rightSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var leftSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        sliderLabel.text = "50"
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func textFieldDoneEditing(sender: UITextField)
    {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    
    
    
    @IBAction func onTapGestureRecognized(_ sender: Any) {
        nameField.resignFirstResponder()
        numberField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    
    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        sliderLabel.text = "\(lroundf(sender.value))"
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func toggleControls(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        //delete the relation between 'Value Changed' and 'View Controller rightSwitch:' in the Sent Events
        //otherwise, it won't works.
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { // "Switches" is selected
            leftSwitch.isHidden = false
            rightSwitch.isHidden = false
            doSomethingButton.isHidden = true
        }else{
            leftSwitch.isHidden = true
            rightSwitch.isHidden = true
            doSomethingButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    @IBAction func onButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBAction func onSwitchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let setting = sender.isOn
        leftSwitch.setOn(setting, animated: true)
        rightSwitch.setOn(setting, animated: true)

    }
}
```

I have checked all relationships about outlet and action.
Is there any place I missed?
Updated：I tried to delete the relationship between 'Value Changed' and 'View Controller rightSwitch:' in the Sent Events. It works~
So, what is this relationship? I didn't add this relationship manually.

Comment: You should put a breakpoint there and see if anything is nil, maybe your `rightSwitch ` is not properly linked to storyboard.

Comment: @Tj3n Yeah. I tried to delete the relation between 'Value Changed' and 'View Controller rightSwitch:' in the Sent Events. It works~